# Adding elements to a NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I know we could just use a `NSMutableArray` for the object, but what if that's not an option and we need to add new elements to an `NSArray`. How would we go about doing this?

My immediate answer would be to create a `NSMutableArray` with the original `NSArray`, add the new elements to it, then cast the `NSMutableArray` back to the original `NSArray`.

I was asked this in an interview and am curious what a correct solution might be, besides just use a `NSMutableArray` in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil];

array = [array arrayByAddingObject:@"Three"];
```

or

```
NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Three", @"Four", nil];

array = [array arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:newArray];
```

Comment: Let's suppose I have a **very** large array. What would be the most efficient way of doing what OP asks? Your solution, or the mutableCopy->add->cast solution proposed by OP?

Comment: Most efficient. Mutable array. Then the array by adding in my method. i dunno though. Test it and let me know your findings :-)

Comment: I tested this and they turned out to be the same as long as you're only adding one more element, regardless of the size. Here's the long explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26517217/1564332

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mutableCopy` on your `NSArray` object to return an `NSMutableArray` containing the previous objects.

Answer (score 3):

`NSArray` objects are *immutable* so they cannot be modified.  The only option is to create a new `NSArray` (via an intermediate `NSMutableArray` object perhaps) and put this new array back into the owning object (if it allows it).

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering what the performance difference would be between using `arrayByAddingObject` and creating a mutable copy and then adding **one** element.

I found that it doesn't matter.

Here's what I used

```
- (IBAction)doTest
{
    for(int n = 0; n < 7; n++){
        [self runTestWithExponent:n];
    }
    NSLog(@"done");
}

- (void)runTestWithExponent:(double)exponent
{
    int arraySize = pow(10.0, exponent);

    NSMutableArray *originalMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:arraySize];
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
        [originalMutableArray addObject:@(i)];
    }
    NSArray *originalArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:originalMutableArray];
    originalMutableArray = nil;

    //test first time
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSArray *newArray = [originalArray arrayByAddingObject:@(-1)];
    NSTimeInterval time1 = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:now];
    newArray = nil;

    //test second time
    now = [NSDate date];
    NSMutableArray *mutable = [originalArray mutableCopy];
    [mutable addObject:@(-1)];
    NSTimeInterval time2 = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:now];
    mutable = nil;

    NSString *winner = (time1 == time2) ? @"same" : ((time1 < time2) ? @"arrayByAdding" : @"mutable");
    NSLog(@"%i : %f --- %f : %@ %f%%", arraySize, time1, time2, winner, (time1/time2 * 100));
}
```

As you can see, I test different array sizes. Sizes of 1, 10, 100 ... 1,000,000. I found regardless of size, the times are very similar to each other. For any given length, sometimes one method is faster, and others, the other. I'm guessing internally they do the same thing.

Here's the output of three runs:

```
1 : 0.000026 --- 0.000034 : arrayByAdding 76.491228%
10 : 0.000011 --- 0.000011 : same 100.000000%
100 : 0.000021 --- 0.000024 : arrayByAdding 87.344913%
1000 : 0.000228 --- 0.000260 : arrayByAdding 87.689133%
10000 : 0.001458 --- 0.001406 : mutable 103.696638%
100000 : 0.015396 --- 0.015625 : arrayByAdding 98.534393%
1000000 : 0.158018 --- 0.162849 : arrayByAdding 97.033438%
done
1 : 0.000011 --- 0.000012 : arrayByAdding 92.039801%
10 : 0.000012 --- 0.000014 : arrayByAdding 85.531915%
100 : 0.000020 --- 0.000025 : arrayByAdding 79.952267%
1000 : 0.000185 --- 0.000144 : mutable 128.435430%
10000 : 0.001397 --- 0.001437 : arrayByAdding 97.216807%
100000 : 0.014448 --- 0.014132 : mutable 102.235803%
1000000 : 0.145622 --- 0.149862 : arrayByAdding 97.170746%
done
1 : 0.000013 --- 0.000012 : mutable 107.920792%
10 : 0.000011 --- 0.000013 : arrayByAdding 84.862385%
100 : 0.000025 --- 0.000029 : arrayByAdding 86.036961%
1000 : 0.000165 --- 0.000135 : mutable 122.207506%
10000 : 0.001547 --- 0.001470 : mutable 105.242884%
100000 : 0.014817 --- 0.014337 : mutable 103.347954%
1000000 : 0.146554 --- 0.148468 : arrayByAdding 98.710857%
done
```

Keep in mind that this was only tested for adding one element. I suspect that (for example) adding 500 elements to the 1,000 sized array will probably be faster using the second method, but I leave such experiments to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a trick question. `NSArrays` are immutable and cannot be altered without creating a new `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` from the previous array, plain and simple.